# No-activate child windows

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

I have a normal window, and I want to add a button, which can be pressed in my window when it's inactive, and this won't steal the focus from the currently active window.

**Example:** Touch keyboard button in the system taskbar of Windows 8/8.1/10, this one:

[image]

Please note an active application is still active when this button is clicked, but the focus goes to the taskbar when its empty space is clicked.

**Classic solutions:**

- To make a whole top-level window non-activatable, WS_EX_NOACTIVATE ex-style can be used. Unfortunately, this style causes a lot of problems with top-level windows, and it cannot be applied to child windows.
- Commonly recommended approach is to listen to WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message and answer MA_NOACTIVATE in case the control was clicked. This works, but only partially: The window won't be activated during the clicks, but the previously active window loses the active state, and GetForegroundWindow returns 0. This can be solved by remembering the last active window (either by periodical polling, or by monitoring EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND or HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED / HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED), and by forcibly restoring it. A lot of headache actually.

Comment: Are you sure about `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE`? That doesn't match my experience of it.

Comment: Clicking a button requires SetCapture() to work.  MSDN docs point out that this function can only work for the foreground window.  Other than bumbling along with the MouseUp notification, boilerplate is to have such keyboard popups *not* use child controls.  It only needs to look like a button, not that hard to paint.

Comment: A question ought to have, you know, a question.

Answer (score 1):

**Win7-way:**

Since Windows 7, there's a new **undocumented** API-function SetChildWindowNoActivate, with ordinal 2005 in user32.dll. It can be declared like this (Delphi-style):

```
function SetChildWindowNoActivate(ChildWnd: HWND): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'user32.dll' index 2005;
```

This function is used in Windows 8/8.1/10 to make no-activate buttons like Touch keyboard, Virtual touchpad and Language switcher.

Here's a screenshot of a sample application with a pushed no-activate button and an active Explorer window above it:

[image]

Comment: Ack! Undocumented API functions! This should come with a much bigger warning label.

Comment: more info - http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/user32.dll/NtUserSetChildWindowNoActivate.php